# Can I use CouchSurfing as as proof of accommodation for a Schengen visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, iceland, couchsurfing

Can one use CouchSurfing to prove accommodation for a Schengen visa to Iceland from India?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is nothing in the regulations that *prevents* an applicant from using a hospitality exchange or social networking for accommodation.

They would treat these arrangements in the same way as if friends were offering you a place, but since they are not real friends, you will need to be a bit careful with how you present your evidence.  It means you can't just say 'couchsurfing' on your application; instead you'll need to demonstrate that firm arrangements are in place with each provider and that these arrangements are an acceptable substitute for a personal invitation.

It would be wise to include a 'backup provider' for each place you plan to stay to show that you have a contingency if the planned accommodation is not available or turns out to be unsafe or unlawful or otherwise unacceptable.

Comment: Thanks for being very clear the answer was quite helpful indeed

Comment: thank you so much for the elaborate explanation gayot fow, but may i ask you how could i present to the officer( custom)?? should i use my phone screenshot the couchsurfing successfully page?? or may i ask you how would you recommend me to do it??